# Case when statement is not giving desired result

Tags: sql-server, null, case

I am trying to execute the below query.

```
Select distinct 
              Case 
              WHEN S.FileStatusIdentifier = 'Invalid'   Then  'Invalid(file<300KB)'
              WHEN S.FileStatusIdentifier = 'NotFound' Then 'NotFound'
              WHEN F.FileDataOID IS Null THEN 'NoFileData'
              END AS FileStatusIdentifier 
              from FileState S
                           Inner Join FileData F ON F.FileDataOID = S.FileDataOID
```

But when I execute the query it is giving the result as below.

*FilestatusIdentifier*
NULL
Invalid(file<300KB)
NotFound

wherever the filedataoid is null, it should give the output as 'NoFileData'. But am getting the NULL. Can somebody help me to understand what's wrong with the Query?

Comment: Try to check `FileStatusIdentifier` to  `Null` value 
`Select distinct 
    Case 
              WHEN S.FileStatusIdentifier IS NULL THEN 'Invalid(file<300KB)'
              WHEN S.FileStatusIdentifier = 'Invalid'   Then  'Invalid(file<300KB)'
              WHEN S.FileStatusIdentifier = 'NotFound' Then 'NotFound'              
    END AS FileStatusIdentifier 
, ISNULL( F.FileDataOID, 'NoFileData')
from FileState S Inner Join FileData F ON F.FileDataOID = S.FileDataOID`. Feel free to ask any question.

Comment: Are you sure `filedataoid is null` and not an empty string or something like that? A `NULL` cannot occur, since you are using that attribute in an `inner join`. Can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking if FileStatusIdentifier is null. You have got rows that have fallen through all these checks. Your last check for FileDatOID is null will never be found because that would be excluded by your inner join. If you want to check for that then the inner join should be a left join. And I would also add

```
when s.FileStatusIdentifier is null then 'NullIdentifier'
else s.FileStatusIdentifier
end
```

to catch the rows where the Identifier is null but the ID is not.

Answer (score 0):

It means that no one condition isn't valid.
So you may add `else`. `else_expression` will return if all other conditions evaluate to *FALSE*.

```
Select distinct 
              Case 
              WHEN S.FileStatusIdentifier = 'Invalid'   Then  'Invalid(file<300KB)'
              WHEN S.FileStatusIdentifier = 'NotFound' Then 'NotFound'
              WHEN F.FileDataOID IS Null THEN 'NoFileData'
              ELSE <else_expression>
              END AS FileStatusIdentifier 
              from FileState S
                           Inner Join FileData F ON F.FileDataOID = S.FileDataOID
```